# Curved box within a box with colour borders and opacity

Tags: html, css

I've looked at several Stack Overflow questions and while some have helped me craft what I have so far I sill can't get it to look exactly like what I am after. I am trying to achieve [this](http://www.ryanw.co.uk/box.png).

So far [this is my result](http://www.ryanw.co.uk/box2.png) when viewed.

It seems like it's almost there except for those white corners in the middle area. Can anyone help me work out what im doing wrong? My code is as follows.

HTML:

```
<div class="outerborder">
       <div class="middleborder">   
           <div class="innerborder">
               <div class="contentarea">

                  Text here lalalalala

               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerborder
{
 border-radius:10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

.middleborder
{
 border-radius:10px;
 border: 10px solid rgba(102,153,102, .5);
}

.innerborder
{     
 border-radius:10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

.contentarea
{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 background: #c7c7c7;
}
```

Comment: Why use so many elements and not just one?

Comment: Your 'middleborder' had a white background that was showing because of the border-radius of it's child. You could color its background if you needed, but @SNAG's solution below works great.

Comment: You can actually remove innerborder too. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am editing this further.

Get rid of the `middleborder` and use this.

```
    <style>
        .outerborder
        {
         border-radius:10px;
         border: 1px solid #000;
         background:rgba(102,153,102, .5);
         padding:10px;
        }

        .contentarea
        {
         padding: 10px;
         border-radius:10px;
         background: #c7c7c7;
         border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="outerborder">
         <div class="contentarea">
             Text here lalalalala
         </div>
       </div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Most appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with just 1 element: http://dabblet.com/gist/3559637

HTML:

```
<div class='b'>Text-here lalala</div>
```

CSS:

```
.b {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(102, 153, 102, .5);
    margin: 125px 15px 0;   
}
.b:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px; right: -11px; bottom: -11px; left: -11px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 21px;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: You could also do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/dkdDb/1/ although my way is not the best way, as the green shadow has an opacity to it, but it's got a black shadow beneath it, so there has to be a shadow between the two that's the color of the background.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly why I used a pseudo-element :) The background may be a gradient or an image.

Comment: Is a blank `content` attribute required when using pseudo elements?

Comment: @Ana I really like the simplicity of this. Thanks for the input

Comment: You need to explicitly specify a `content` for the pseudo-element. If you don't need to have anything in it, then you leave just the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="outerborder">
       <div class="contentarea">
          Text here lalalalala
       </div>
</div>

.outerborder
{
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color:rgba(102,153,102, .5);
  padding:10px;
}
.contentarea
{
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background: #c7c7c7;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your making it way more complicated then it needs to be.

Just need 2 divs. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fnycs/